# How do i import another turtle in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

im studying coding in bugaria in  highschool. Im in 8th grade, and were studying python and processing. Since the end of this schoolyear is near, our python teacher gave us a project, he said that the project could be whatever we want. I told him, i would make a racing game, where two turtles race for the win, he just introduced us to how to control your turtle. Now, im going to import another turtle, and assign it WASD, and the first turtle is going to have ARROW KEYS assigned. now. how do i get another turtle, and how do i assign it separate controls?
i would also want to know how i would import a custom image that is a top down racetrack i drew in paint, any help is highly appreciated.
Also, its my first time here.Sorry for bad english, im not american.

Comment: you can instantiate two turtles.  `t1 = turtle.Turtle()`  `t2 = turtle.Turtle()`. Then apply the desired commands and key assignments to either t1 or t2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We aren't interested in what motivates you to learn programming, or the discussion you had with your teacher. We *are* interested in *the problem that you want to solve*. If you have code that does something, and you want to add a feature, it is a good idea to show the existing code - or at least, enough of it that we can see the existing features, and understand the problem. It's also important to ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: If you are specifically trying to make games, you may have better luck on [gamedev.se]. But I really think that the questions you want to ask, will be better on an actual discussion forum, such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: its not a game, its a school project, which yeah, it is a game, but its written in python, so i decided i'd as here since i'll get better results as opposed to quora or reddit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the team! :) May you have lots of fun!
You do not want to **import** a second turtle, but to **instantiate** a second turtle.

Importing refers to importing a library, which runs the library code and allows you to access all the libraries functions. So when you type:

```
import turtle
```

you import / "enable" a set of functions you can refer to. One of them is `turtle.Turtle()`, the result of which is a new turtle object.

After this object is created, you need to store it to a variable, so that you can refer to it and call its functions.This is what the command

```
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
```

does. As @Sembei_Norimaki writes, you can instantiate  many more turtles e.g.
`t2 = turtle.Turtle()`
Each will be a different objects and it is possible e.g. to do

```
t1.forward(30)
t1.penup()
t2.pendown()
```

giving each turtle different commands (or in better terms calling the methods of/on each object)

1 hour ago